# Is there a simple way to count all data extensions within Marketing Cloud business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

We would need to know how many data extensions (including shared) exists with every Marketing Cloud instance. Is there a simple way to do that? Maybe from the parent business unit to see how many of each child instance have data extensions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rest api to list all data extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/340737/rest-api-to-list-all-data-extension)

Comment: The trouble is my non existed knowledge of how to implement Rest API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a simple way to get just the count of the Data Extensions in your BU, go to Setup and scroll down on the first screen, Setup Home. You're going to have to check in each BU separately.

[image]

Shared DEs would have to be counted manually, at least I am not aware of any "simple" ways to get a count of them from the UI.

Comment: That is amazing!