# I want to search the list of SQL Query Activities which uses my target data extension in Select statements without explicitly storing them in DEs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, sql, automationstudio, cloudpage

I'm trying to display the results in the form instead of storing the details in data extension which makes it accessible for everyone with the cloudpage URL.
Here the search is not happening as expected, please suggest changes. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Query Activities by Data Extension</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Search Query Activities by Data Extension</h1>
<form method="post">
<label for="searchTerm">Enter Data Extension Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="searchTerm" id="searchTerm">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<br>
<div id="resultsDiv"></div>

<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");

var searchTerm = Request.GetFormField("searchTerm");
var matchingActivities = []; // An array to hold the matching SQL query activities

if (searchTerm) {
var queryActivities = DataExtension.Init("QueryDefinition").Rows.Retrieve();

for (var i=0; i<queryActivities.length; i++) {
var queryText = queryActivities[i].QueryText;
if (queryText.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
matchingActivities.push(queryActivities[i]);
}
}
}

if (matchingActivities.length > 0) {
Platform.Response.Write("<h2>Matching Query Activities:</h2>");
Platform.Response.Write("<ul>");
for (var j=0; j<matchingActivities.length; j++) {
Platform.Response.Write("<li>" + matchingActivities[j].Name + "</li>");
}
Platform.Response.Write("</ul>");
}
else if (searchTerm) {
Platform.Response.Write("<p>No matching query activities found.</p>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Here the search is not happening as expected_ - can you be more specific? Is the script throwing error 500? Is it creating a wormhole?

Comment: @Lukas Lunow I’m not getting 500 error or any error but when I submit the form with target data extension name which should yield some result but returning else part with “no matching queries found”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You mention that you do not want the cloudpage to be accessible. Your page is insecure even if you enter a search function.

Suggestion - secure it: https://sf-marketing.com/marketing-cloud-user-validation-on-cloudpages/

2. you mention you do not want to store data in a data extension but retrieve the queries directly. However, you actually construct your dataset by retrieving rows *from a data extension* called "QueryDefinition":

```
var queryActivities = DataExtension.Init("QueryDefinition").Rows.Retrieve();
```

Assumption: you want to query the API for QueryDefinitions, not search a DE. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/querydefinition.html

This error can be isolated by three debug messages placed before

```
if (matchingActivities.length > 0) {
```

..namely:

```
Platform.Response.Write("matchingA:" + Stringify(matchingActivities) + "<br>");
Platform.Response.Write("searchTerm:" + searchTerm  + "<br>");
Platform.Response.Write("queryText:" + searchTerm  + "<br>");
 Platform.Response.Write("queryActivities:" + Stringify(queryActivities) + "<br>");
```

which shows that already your first array queryActivities is empty.

3. here is your solution, but actually retrieving queryDefinitions using WSProxy, not trying to search a DE called "QueryDefinition" that probably does not exist in the first place.

limitations:

- This is still insecure
- the search is case sensitive
- it searches querytexts as a whole, so might bring up false positives, not just DE names. E.g if you search "subscriberKey" you'll find a lot of queries.
- I tested it once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Query Activities by Data Extension</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Search Query Activities by Data Extension</h1>
<form method="post">
<label for="searchTerm">Enter Data Extension Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="searchTerm" id="searchTerm">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<br>
<div id="resultsDiv"></div>

<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var searchTerm = Request.GetFormField("searchTerm");
var matchingActivities = []; // An array to hold the matching SQL query activities

var queryActivities = {};
if (searchTerm) {

    var cols = [
        "Name"
        ,"QueryText"
    ];

    var filter = {
        Property: "QueryText", 
        SimpleOperator: "like",
        Value: searchTerm 
    };

    request = api.retrieve("QueryDefinition", cols, filter);
//var queryActivities = DataExtension.Init("QueryDefinition").Rows.Retrieve();
   // Write(Stringify(request));
    
    var results = request.Results
    //Write("<br> results: " + Stringify(results));
    
    for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
        Write(i)
        var queryText = results[i].QueryText
        var queryName = results[i].Name
        Write("queryName" + queryName)
        if (queryText.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
            matchingActivities.push(queryName);
       }
    }
    
}
Platform.Response.Write("matchingA: " + Stringify(matchingActivities) + "<br>");
Platform.Response.Write("searchTerm: " + searchTerm  + "<br>");
Platform.Response.Write("queryText: " + searchTerm  + "<br>");
Platform.Response.Write("queryActivities: " + Stringify(queryActivities) + "<br>");
  
if (matchingActivities.length > 0) {
    Platform.Response.Write("<h2>Matching Query Activities:</h2>");
    Platform.Response.Write("<ul>");
    
    for (var j=0; j<matchingActivities.length; j++) {
        Platform.Response.Write("<li>" + matchingActivities[j] + "</li>");
    }
    Platform.Response.Write("</ul>");
    }
else if (searchTerm) {
Platform.Response.Write("<p>No matching query activities found.</p>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

reference: https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/automation-studio/activities/queries/retrieve/

Comment: Great! Thank you Jonas Laberty. As it searches querytexts as a whole, can we just limit it for identifying target Data Extensions and respective activity name similar to [Data Extension Inventory]:(https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/05/20/inventory-of-data-extensions-and-their-data-sources/) (https://gortonington.com/sfmc-data-extension-inventory-take-2/).

Comment: if you are looking for FROM which DE it pulls, then you need to look at the querytext. If you are looking at which DEs it writes into, in fact you have to look at dataExtensionTarget and can also use exact matching, as it is a genuine field and not free text.

Comment: Thank you Jonas! This really helped a lot.

Comment: A follow up question: Is it possible to pull the folder path of searching Data Extension within the same solution. In the sense can we combine the solution for searching the list of query activities using DE name and display the folder path of specified DE within same script. I am new to SSJS and could use some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: recommend to open a follow up question. I am probably the only person on stackexchange reading it here, vs. the whole community will see a new question ;)

Comment: I tried creating a new question, kind of got a notification saying it's a repetitive question / already answered. However, my query involves combination of solution within same ask which is not repetative I believe. I tried some workaround, my lack of knowledge is ssjs pulling me back. Kindly request you to help on the same.

Comment: your question has indeed been answered: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49814/retrieving-folders-and-subfolders-of-an-exacttarget-data-extension-with-soap /  - you will probably never find your exact usecase answered in a 500 character comment. If the linked answer doesn't help, you have to familiarize yourself with the various docs:
https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/contact-builder/dataextensions/retrieve/ - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/datafolder.html https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextension.html

Comment: Thanks for the resources Jonas :)